# How to adjust brightness in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.1?

Tags: brightness, acer, function-keys

Previously I used [brightness fix](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) but it is not working in this version.My laptop model is Acer Aspire 5740 and graphic card is of Intel

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16.04 brightness fix is no longer required. Remove all your previous fixes for it and let `systemd` restore brightness automatically based on you `system Settings`, `Brightnesss & Lock` settings:

[image: Brightness & Lock]